# How to keep switch statement continuing in Java

Tags: java, while-loop, switch-statement, console-application, infinite-loop

I'm looking to keep the following menu repeating:

> Choose an Option
>
> 1 - FIND
>
> 2 - IN-SHUFFLE
>
> 3 - OUT-SHUFFLE

So that when a user selects an option (and this will be executed), afterwards they can select other options as well.

**Problem:** My code keeps the menu repeating without stopping.

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MainMenu {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int userChoice;
        userChoice = menu();
    }

    private static int menu() {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Choose an Option");
        System.out.println("1 - FIND");
        System.out.println("2 - IN-SHUFFLE");
        System.out.println("3 - OUT-SHUFFLE");

        int choice = scanner.nextInt();
        boolean quit = false;
        do {
            System.out.println("Choose an Option");
            switch (choice) {
                case 1:
                    System.out.println("\n1 - FIND\n");
                    //Deck.findTop();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    System.out.println("\n2 - IN-SHUFFLE\n");
                    // call method
                    break;
                case 3:
                    System.out.println("\n3 - OUT-SHUFFLE\n");
                    // call method
                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.println("\nInvalid Option");
                    break;
            }
        }
        while (!quit);

        return choice;
    }

}
```

I'm not sure how I can stop it from constantly repeating.

Comment: Add an option to quit

Comment: And place ```int choice = scanner.nextInt();``` in the loop

Answer (score 0):

The selected option stays the same throughout the loop. You need to set `quit`to true for the loop to exit.
I suggest adding an option to quit to the switch statement, where you do just that.

To be able to change the selected option, you need to ask for input inside the loop.

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
int choice;
boolean quit = false;
do {
  choice = sc.nextInt();
  switch (choice) {
    case 1:
      // case 1
      break;
    case 2:
      // case 2
      break;
    case 3:
      // case 3
      break;
    case 4:
      quit = true;
      break;
    default:
      // your default here
  }
} while (!quit);
```

Answer (score 0):

One issue in your code is that method `menu` returns an option, So it can either be used to read only an option from the console, or to do the whole dialog, until the user decides to quit. The latter is better IMHO because it keeps the display of the menu close to the `switch` statemenmt:

```
private static void menu()
{
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Choose an Option");
    System.out.println("1 - FIND");
    System.out.println("2 - IN-SHUFFLE");
    System.out.println("3 - OUT-SHUFFLE");
    System.out.println("4 - QUIT");

    boolean quit = false;
    do {
        System.out.println("Choose an Option");
        int choice = scanner.nextInt();

        switch (choice) {
            case 1:
                System.out.println("\n1 - FIND\n");
                Deck.findTop();
                break;
            case 2:
                System.out.println("\n2 - IN-SHUFFLE\n");
                // call method
                break;
            case 3:
                System.out.println("\n3 - OUT-SHUFFLE\n");
                // call method
                break;
            case 4:
                System.out.println("\n4 - QUIT");
                quit = true;
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("\nInvalid Option");
                break;
        }
    }
    while (!quit);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this. You just have to move quit out of loop and bring in opions and userchoice into loop.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Switchh {

static boolean quit = false;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int userChoice;
    userChoice = menu();
}

private static int menu() {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    int choice;
    do {

        System.out.println("Choose an Option");
        System.out.println("1 - FIND");
        System.out.println("2 - IN-SHUFFLE");
        System.out.println("3 - OUT-SHUFFLE");
        choice = scanner.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Choose an Option");
        switch (choice) {
            case 1:
                System.out.println("\n1 - FIND\n");
                //Deck.findTop();
                break;
            case 2:
                System.out.println("\n2 - IN-SHUFFLE\n");
                // call method
                break;
            case 3:
                System.out.println("\n3 - OUT-SHUFFLE\n");
                // call method
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("\nInvalid Option");
                quit = true;
                break;
        }
    }
    while (!quit);

    return choice;
}

}
```

Comment: @hc_dev seems the question is modified, checkout the edited ans

Answer (score 0):

#### What happens?

1. User's choice (`int choice = scanner.nextInt();`) is only asked once before the loop. So the `choice` is fix before entering the loop.
2. Your `do {} while` loops only the switch-statement which executes some code, based on the user's choice (actually prints single *fixed* choice). The user has no chance to change this inside the loop.
3. The loop's control-variable `boolean quit` is never changed inside your loop, so exit condition of your loop `quit == true` will never be reached.
4. the menu you're showing the user does not contain any option to quit `4 - QUIT`

**Summary:** Once user enters a choice (1), the program gets stuck in a so called **infinite-loop** (3) always printing the current choice (2). Even after a restart the uninformed user has no chance to exit, since neither the menu does list this option (4), nor would `choice = 4` have an effect since it's not in switch's cases (3).

#### Resolving Issues

1. Modify the loop's control-variable inside the loop: set `quit = true` inside an additional `case 4: quit = true; break;`
2. Make sure this *only exiting* branch will accessed by reading user's choice inside the loop: put `int choice = scanner.nextInt();` inside `do {}` and directly before `switch`.
3. Add an option to your menu so user knows how to exit (e.g. `4 - QUIT`), and use this option  (see 1)
4. Show the menu inside the loop, directly before reading the user's choice.

#### Recommendations

**Design the loop first: focus on exit!**

1. Use `while(exitCondition == false) {}` loops instead of `do {} while(exitConfition == false)` because very important `exitCondition` is shown first (to every reader of your code), and it's controlling and avoiding an **infinite-loop**. So, rememeber setting it inside the loop!
2. Keep the code-lines inside your loop short, and modify control-variables on top, not inside nested blocks.
3. When designing loops (especially for user-interaction), do it first, and use pseudo-code (see lines commented out below).

```java
    final static int QUIT_OPTION = 4;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int chosenOption = -1;
        while (chosenOption != QUIT_OPTION) {
            // showMenu();
            // chosenOption = readUsersChoice();   
            // executeOption(chosenOption);
            System.out.println("choosenOption: " = choosenOption); // for testing: see if choosenOption does change
            choosenOption = QUIT_OPTION; // while design: simulates a single loop
        }
    }
```

The last 2 lines inside the loop are only for design-phase, where you will test a single loop (hence the final activating of `QUIT_OPTION`). Put your focus on the control-variable: Is your user or program able to change it in desired way (hence the debugging `println`)?

**Divide and conquer: split task/logic into small separate functions**
The loop above (inside `main`) was the first small but main part of logic.

First task inside the loop: "displaying a menu"

```java
    private static void showMenu() {
        System.out.println("Options - Main Menu");
        System.out.println("1 - FIND");
        System.out.println("2 - IN-SHUFFLE");
        System.out.println("3 - OUT-SHUFFLE");
        System.out.println("4 - QUIT");
        System.out.println("Choose from above Options (1-4) by typing the number followed by RETURN:");
    }
```

Try to keep this methods small, focused on one task. If possible keep them also isolated (from others). So you can test (call) them separately and check if the do what you want.

Next: "read the user's choice"

```java
    private static int readUsersChoice() {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int choice = scanner.nextInt();

        return choice;
    }
```

This method needs special testing. Try what's happening if user enters a letter (e.g. `Q` because wishing to quit). Did you catch the `java.util.InputMismatchException` inside the method?

Finally the "choosen option will be evaluated and executed":

```java
    private static void executeOption(int choice) {
        switch (choice) {
            case 1:
                System.out.println("\n1 - FIND\n");
                //Deck.findTop();
                break;
            case 2:
                System.out.println("\n2 - IN-SHUFFLE\n");
                // call method
                break;
            case 3:
                System.out.println("\n3 - OUT-SHUFFLE\n");
                // call method
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("\nInvalid Option");
                break;
        }
    }
```

Test it well, since here -based on an option- some other code/methods (even loops) could be called. You can also add the `case: QUIT_OPTION` and print a Good-Bye.